# Database querying through Http in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails app , In which I have created a table Product Name:string and Number: integer.

The application should give user a form where he can search a product by his number if product exists it should give product name from database.

My search.html.erb is this.

```
    <%= form_for @products, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:class =>   "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :number, :size => "60x12" %>
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
    <% end
```

What will be the definition of search Method in ProductController and routes i need to add in routes.rb?

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of nifty forms, this is how I would have done this:
In `config/routes.rb`
replace `resources :products'` with

```
resources :products do 
  post 'search', :on => :collection
end
```

This will give me a `search_products_path`

In your view:

```
<%= form_for(:search, :url => search_products_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :number, :placeholder => "Enter number to search" %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

In your `products_controller.rb`

```
def search
  number = params[:search][:number]
  @result = Product.find_by_number(number)
  @not_found = true unless @result
end
```

In your `views/products/search.html.erb`, use `@result` to show the product information; take care while checking whether or not the desired product is actually found or not. I have set the boolean @not_found in case it doesn't exist.

Comment: i am getting this error on search page .Couldn't find Product with id=search

Comment: After passing through controller action to `search.html.erb` ?

Comment: I am getting this error after updating all the files suggested by you then navigating to products/search.

Comment: I have change routes post path to get as through post path it was referring to show method but now i am getting error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: @DeependerSingla, Please check that you do not have `resources :products` anywhere else in your `routes.rb`. If it is there, please remove that single line.

Comment: I don't have it else where resources:products  in my routes.rb . Do i need to remove show method in my ProductContoller.